# ros2 ackermann robot not moving forward, left and right

Tags: ros2, urdf, ros-humble, ros2-control, robot-description

I am working on a ros2 ackermann steering robot with 4 wheels.

Issue: The robot is not moving forward, left and right. Although its wheels are turning left and right. The robot is moving in reverse direction properly.

There are 4 wheels. Out of it, 2 rear wheels are of type `continuous` and 2 front wheels are of type `revolute`.

Distro: `ros2-humble`

Full code with steps to reproduce error is available at: https://github.com/nice-user1/ros2_acker/tree/master

Edit: The issue is resolved and the updated working code is pushed to the same branch.

## Directory Structure

```
race_it_ws
    /src
        /race_it
            /description
                /race_car.xacro
                /ros2_ack.xacro
                /inertial.xacro
            /config
                /controller
                    /my_controllers.yaml
            /launch
                /rsp.launch.py
```

## Code

### Description

#### race_car.xacro (main urdf file)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="simple_car">

<xacro:include filename="inertial.xacro"/>
<!-- <xacro:include filename="gazebo_control_dd.xacro"/> -->
<!-- <xacro:include filename="gazebo_control_steer.xacro"/> -->

    
    <xacro:property name="wheel_width" value="0.04"/>
    <xacro:property name="wheel_radius" value="0.1"/>
    
    <!-- Wheel macro -->
    <xacro:macro name="wheel" params="name"> 
        <link name="${name}">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="${wheel_width}" radius="${wheel_radius}" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="blue"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="${wheel_width}" radius="${wheel_radius}" />
            </geometry>
        </collision>
         <xacro:inertial_cylinder mass="0.1" length="${wheel_width}" radius="${wheel_radius}"/>    
        </link>
        
        <gazebo reference="${name}">
            <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
        </gazebo>   

    </xacro:macro>



  <!-- Base Link -->
  
  <link name="base_link">
  </link>

  <!-- Chassis Link -->
  <link name="chassis_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.5 1.0 0.2"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <material name="blue">
        <color rgba="0 0 1 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>

    <xacro:inertial_box mass="0.5" x="0.5" y="1.0" z="0.15"/>

  </link>
    
  <gazebo reference="chassis_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
  </gazebo>   

  
 <!-- Base Chassis Joint -->
  <joint name="base_chassis_joint" type="fixed">
      <parent link="base_link"/>
      <child link="chassis_link"/>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.2" rpy="0 0 0 "/>
  </joint>    
    
  
  <!-- Front Left Wheel -->
  <xacro:wheel name="front_left_link"/>
  
  <joint name="front_left_joint" type="revolute">
        <parent link="chassis_link"/>
        <child link="front_left_link"/>
        <origin xyz="-0.25 0.5 -0.1" rpy="0 ${-pi/2} 0"/>
        <limit upper="0.5236" lower="-0.5236" velocity="20" effort="1"/>
        <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  
   <gazebo reference="front_left_link">
       <material>Gazebo/Red</material>   
       <!--
       <mu1 value="0.001"/>
       <mu2 value="0.001"/>
       -->
   </gazebo>
  
  
  <!-- Front Right Wheel -->
  <xacro:wheel name="front_right_link"/>
  
  <joint name="front_right_joint" type="revolute">
        <parent link="chassis_link"/>
        <child link="front_right_link"/>
        <origin xyz="0.25 0.5 -0.1" rpy="0 ${-pi/2} 0"/>
        <limit upper="0.5236" lower="-0.5236" velocity="20" effort="1"/>
        <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  
  <gazebo reference="front_right_link">   
       <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
       <!--
       <mu1 value="0.001"/>
       <mu2 value="0.001"/>
       -->
  </gazebo>
  
  
  <!-- Rear Left Wheel -->
  <xacro:wheel name="rear_left_link"/>
  
  <joint name="rear_left_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="chassis_link"/>
        <child link="rear_left_link"/>
        <origin xyz="-0.25 -0.5 -0.1" rpy="0 ${-pi/2} 0"/>
        <limit upper="0.5236" lower="-0.5236" velocity="20" effort="1"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
  </joint>
    
  <!-- Rear Right Wheel -->  
  <xacro:wheel name="rear_right_link" />
  
  <joint name="rear_right_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="chassis_link"/>
        <child link="rear_right_link"/>
        <origin xyz="0.25 -0.5 -0.1" rpy="0 ${-pi/2} 0"/> <!-- Default value for x is "0.27" -->
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
  </joint>
  
  <xacro:include filename="ros2_ack.xacro"/>
      
</robot>
```

#### inertial.xacro (for inertia)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" >

    <!-- Specify some standard inertial calculations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia -->
    <!-- These make use of xacro's mathematical functionality -->

    <xacro:macro name="inertial_box" params="mass x y z">
        <inertial>
            <mass value="${mass}" />
        <inertia ixx="${(1/12) * mass * (y*y+z*z)}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
                    iyy="${(1/12) * mass * (x*x+z*z)}" iyz="0.0"
                izz="${(1/12) * mass * (x*x+y*y)}" />
        </inertial>
    </xacro:macro>


    <xacro:macro name="inertial_cylinder" params="mass length radius">
        <inertial>
            <mass value="${mass}" />
        <inertia ixx="${(1/12) * mass * (3*radius*radius + length*length)}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
                    iyy="${(1/12) * mass * (3*radius*radius + length*length)}" iyz="0.0"
                izz="${(1/2) * mass * (radius*radius)}" />
        </inertial>
    </xacro:macro>


</robot>
```

#### ros2_ack.xacro

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="simple_car">
    <ros2_control name="carbot" type="system">
        <hardware>
            <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
                        
            <!-- 
            <plugin>ros2_control_demo_example_11/CarlikeBotSystemHardware</plugin>
            <param name="example_param_hw_start_duration_sec">0</param>
            <param name="example_param_hw_stop_duration_sec">3.0</param>
            <param name="is_simulation">1</param>
            -->       
        </hardware>
        
        <!-- Front Left Wheel -->        
        <joint name="front_left_joint">
            <command_interface name="position"/>
            <state_interface name="position" />
        </joint>     
      
          <!-- Front Right Wheel -->         
          <joint name="front_right_joint">
            <command_interface name="position"/>
            <state_interface name="position" />
          </joint>       
          
          <!-- Rear Left Wheel -->          
          <joint name="rear_left_joint">
              <command_interface name="velocity"/>
              <state_interface name="velocity" />
          </joint>
            
          <!-- Rear Right Wheel -->            
          <joint name="rear_right_joint">
              <command_interface name="velocity"/>
              <state_interface name="velocity" />
          </joint>      
    </ros2_control>
    
    <gazebo>
        <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">
            <parameters>$(find race_it)/config/controller/my_controllers.yaml</parameters>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>
    
</robot>
```

### config (controller)

#### my_controllers.xacro

```
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 30
    
    use_sim_time: true
    
    asc:
        type: ackermann_steering_controller/AckermannSteeringController       
    
    jsc:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster
    
asc:
  ros__parameters:

    reference_timeout: 2.0
    front_steering: true
    open_loop: false
    velocity_rolling_window_size: 10
    position_feedback: false
    use_stamped_vel: true

    rear_wheels_names: [rear_right_joint, rear_left_joint]
    front_wheels_names: [front_right_joint, front_left_joint]


    wheelbase: 1.0
    front_wheel_track: 0.5
    rear_wheel_track: 0.5
    front_wheels_radius: 0.1
    rear_wheels_radius: 0.1
    
    
#jsc:
#  ros__parameters:
#    type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
```

### launch

#### rsp.launch.py

```
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch_ros.actions import Node
import launch_ros

from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource


import xacro


def generate_launch_description():

    # Check if we're told to use sim time
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')

    # Process the URDF file
    pkg_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('race_it'))
    
    #xacro_file = os.path.join(pkg_path,'description','robot.urdf.xacro')
    xacro_file = os.path.join(pkg_path,'description', 'race_car.xacro')
    
    robot_description_config = xacro.process_file(xacro_file)
    
    default_rviz_config_path = os.path.join(pkg_path, 'config/rviz/urdf_config.rviz')
    
    # Create a robot_state_publisher node
    params = {'robot_description': robot_description_config.toxml(), 'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}
    node_robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[params]
    )
    
    
        
    joint_state_publisher_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher',
        executable='joint_state_publisher',
        name='joint_state_publisher'
    )
    

    rviz_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='rviz2',
        executable='rviz2',
        name='rviz2',
        output='screen',
        arguments=['-d', default_rviz_config_path],
    )

    
    gazebo = IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
            get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros'), 'launch', 'gazebo.launch.py')])#,
    #        launch_arguments={'world': "my_bot/worlds/obstacles.world"}.items()
    )
    
    
    spawn_entity = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='gazebo_ros',
        executable='spawn_entity.py',
        arguments=['-entity', '', '-topic', 'robot_description'],
        output='screen'
    )


    # Launch!
    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_sim_time',
            default_value='true',
            description='Use sim time if true'),

        node_robot_state_publisher,
        joint_state_publisher_node,
        rviz_node,
        gazebo,
        spawn_entity
    ])
```

**To Execute:**

- ros2 launch race_it rsp.launch.py
- ros2 run controller_manager spawner asc

NOTE: I feel there are some issues with the robot_description due to which i am experiencing this weird behavior although I haven't been able to figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide a self-contained public repo with your files to reproduce your issue.

Comment: The code is available at "https://github.com/nice-user1/ros2_acker/tree/master". 
Steps to reproduce the issue are present in the "README.md".

The second package "temp_teleop" is same code as "teleop_twist_keyboard" but modified to use "stamped" values. Also it stops the bot after 0.2 seconds so there is need to press the key continuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the design of the robot. The front 2 wheels were connected to the main chassi using "revolute joint" and not using "continous joint". Because of the friction of the front wheels, the robot was not able to move forward, left and right although its wheels moved left and right.

A quick fix for this issue is to remove the friction of the front wheels by adding the following code in the  tag of the front 2 wheels:

```
   <mu1 value="0.001"/>
   <mu2 value="0.001"/>
```

The other permanent fix was to add 2 additional link to the front 2 wheels as "revolute" joint and connect the wheels to this link as continuous joint.
[image: Image showing the added links.]

I have added the additional links and the updated code can be found at https://github.com/nice-user1/ros2_acker/tree/master.

Answer (score 0):

I believe modifying your ros2_ack.xacro file solves this issue. Try adding the following line inside the rear wheels' joint tags:

```xml
<state_interface name="position"/>
```

At least, in my simulation, removing this causes quite a few problems.

Comment: It is not working for me. Is it working for you?
Also it dosen't makes any sense because as far as I know, "state_interface" is just for getting feedback, it is the the "controller_interface" which controls the robot.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that you don't have a continuous joint for the front wheels. So, they can only turn left or right and can't rotate as wheels should.

My sim inside gazebo doesn't have any issues. You can take a look at my approach here: https://github.com/BalazsPh21/ARS

Comment: I tried using your package directly by following the steps given the in your repository. Your robot is acting weird in rviz when base link is set to odom and i turn it left or right. It starts rotating in its won axis although its movement is ok in gazebo. It sill is moving very slowly in gazebo.
One more question? Are you using linux or window because i saw XTerm which i think is an emulator for windows.

Comment: Sorry, I've just been busy with my exams. I'm aware of that issue in RViz, I couldn't seem to find what causes it. I will ask for help here on that regard. To your other question, yes, I'm using Ubuntu (22.04 specifically). Using xterm, was the easiest solution (I could find) to run the teleop node in a new terminal window. Also, I'm only using teleop for debugging purposes. I'm not planning on keeping it included.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with the issue. I have posted the solution .